# How to calculate the new global position of a child object based on a relative change in the parent?

Tags: c++, math

I have a spatial structure where I keep a few objects. All the positions of the objects are global.

I'm now trying to create a parent/child system but I'm having trouble with the math. What I tried at first was, everytime I move an object, I also move all of its children by the same amount. That works but I also need rotation, so I tried using matrixes. I built a model matrix for the child. It was built using the relative `position`/`rotation`/`scale` to the parent:

```
glm::mat4 child_model;
//"this" is the parent
child_model = glm::translate(child_model, child_spatial.position - this->m_position);
child_model = child_model * glm::toMat4(glm::inverse(this->m_rotation) * child_spatial.rotation);
child_model = glm::scale(child_model, child_spatial.scale - this->m_scale);
```

I would then rotate/translate/scale the child matrix by the amount the parent was rotated/moved/scaled and then I would decompose the resulting matrix back to the global child:

```
child_model = child_model * glm::toMat4(this->m_rotation * rotation);
child_model = glm::translate(child_model, this->m_position + position);
child_model = glm::scale(child_model, this->m_scale * scale);
```

where position/rotation/scale are defined as:

```
//How much the parent changed
position = this->position - m_position;
rotation = glm::inverse(m_rotation) * this->rotation;
scale = this->scale - m_scale;
```

and:

```
glm::decompose(child_model, d_scale, d_rotation, d_translation, d_skew, d_perspective);
child_spatial.position = d_translation;
child_spatial.rotation = d_rotation;
child_spatial.scale = d_scale;
```

But it doesn't work and I'm not sure what is wrong. Everything just spins/moves out of control. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is similar to joint animation used for computer animations. First you have to use or construct transformation matrices for each object. However, the transformation matrix of each child object should be with respect to their parent's coordinate system (i.e., child coordinate should be in parent's coordinate space). We'll call this matrix a `ToParentMatrix`. In addition, each object needs to have another matrix which transforms it all the way to the root (which is in world space). We'll call this matrix a`ToRootMatrix`. When we multiply these two matrices we get a 'ToWorldMatrix' which contains the position and orientation in world space. So the transformation of each object to world space is as follows in a 2-joint hierarchie (root, child1 (of root) and child2 (of child1)):

```
RootTransform = ToWorldMatrix; // The root object is allready in world space;
Child1.ToRootMatrix = RootTransform;
Child1.ToWorldMatrix = Child1.ToRootMatrix*Child1.ToParentMatrix;

Child2.ToRootMatrix = Child1.ToWorldMatrix;
Child2.ToWorldMatrix = Child2.ToRootMatrix*Child2.ToParentMatrix;
```

For more information, search for joint (or skeletal) animation and forward kinematics. Also [Frank Luna's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1936420228) has two nice chapters about skeletal animation.

Answer (score -4):

You are way overthinking things because you are missing some math fundamentals. There are tons of linear algebra for 3d graphics tutorials and courses just a google away!

You need to read through some of them. Your mistake is that you think of a matrix as "how to apply scale/translate/rotate". You need to change that point of view. Matrices describe local spaces. It does not matter how you set them up. So stop thinking about "how things move". Think of every matrix as a space (base). Multiplying a vector by a matrix moves it into that space. And then you move it to the next space. Think of a space as a relative coordinate system.

This is probably not very helpful, but what I am trying to say is: Spend some time to study how linear algebra works! You will need it and it is quite easy in the end. I have a hard time finding a good tutorial but maybe https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra looks good.

Comment: The link is great and I'm going through the course. But this is not really an answer :(